# Get data from URL as jQuery AJAX do in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post

I want to get data of a URL with sending some POST data. In simple word, as jQuery AJAX gets data, I want that in PHP. Similar of this code in PHP.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: file_get_contents('your_target_url'); can get data from your requested url.

Comment: file_get_contents does not work with post - google for curl, (Curl URL Request Library)

Comment: Yes u can curl for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **curl** for that. there is a great tutorial on that by davidwalsh [here](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

```
//extract data from the post
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields = array(
    'lname' => urlencode($_POST['last_name']),
    'fname' => urlencode($_POST['first_name']),
    'title' => urlencode($_POST['title']),
    'company' => urlencode($_POST['institution']),
    'age' => urlencode($_POST['age']),
    'email' => urlencode($_POST['email']),
    'phone' => urlencode($_POST['phone'])
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```